# connecting to mysql databsae with json on android map

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-maps

does anyone have any json tutorials that are easy enough to understand for a complete beginner (or if possible someone to show mehow to do it :)?

what i'm attempting is to create and android application that retrieves longitude and lattitude coordinates from my mysql database then displays an image on the map where the coordinate matches up. when clicked an overlay appears and displays the event name and address for event.

what i've been able to achieve is the following:
1) create android map project
2)display a fixed coordinate that is saved within the source (not what i want to do but hey)
3)when 2 is clicked an overlay appears with some text that is saved within the source (again not what i want but a start)
the long+lat and name + address of the event are located within the database.
i've been made aware that i will need to use json (as i don't know how to use it i'm asking for a noob proof tutorial)

i've had a look at 
[connecting to mysql database](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)
the best i've been able to achieve on this is upto the php part. after this i don't understand what needs to be done (hence the request)

Comment: Starter for 10 - look at web services, namely RESTful ones as good start. 
You need an data on server somewhere that your program can query via something like JSON using an API

Comment: don't mean to be rude but that's made no sense to me at all lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good article to fetch data from mysql using json, http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/. and here is another link that used to display location on google map, http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/01/01/android/getting-started-with-android-map-view/.

Comment: thanks. the creating a point tutorial i've passed that stage, i can plot 1 object on the map no problem. the problem comes in connecting to my db. the other link oyu've provided connwecting to mysql using php ive used this and got to the php part and then i got stuck. its the json part i dont understand how to do

Comment: the code for retrievoing the data from server does that go into my main class or do i make a seperate class?

Comment: See, we use php to connect mysql from android. We use url of php file in java code in android and establish a connection from android to php.

Comment: Now PHP script contains SQL query and a code to connect mysql. According to query, it retrieves data from database. Now the question is that how to send this data from php to android. This can be done using two method,by encoding data into JSON Format and other is creating XML file of data. Both are good, and it depends on the requirement, but mostly in this case, JSON is used more. So, by using JSON we can send data to android. In android, we need to write code that decode the data from JSON format. So, this is the thing.

Answer (score 0):

no offense taken...
you need to break down your big problem into smaller problems.

```
Phone <---magic----> server
```

the 3 keys parts are the phone stuff, the server stuff and the 'how they talk' stuff. Answering each of these here is a bit beyond the scope of the question but hopefully this will start you on the path enlightenment (of which there are many). 
The phone and the server where this data comes from need to communicate somehow. An easy way to this is using JSON (over http). The phone also needs to know what it can ask the server, which is handled (in very general terms) by using API of sorts.
A good start would probably be look here (and on google) for things such as 'using a web service in an Android App'.

Comment: ah. thanks for putting it into dummy terms lol. i've got a server setup where i've put my php file which opens a db connection then executes a select * statement.